# PHP Remove duplicates from multidimensional array based on key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array ($array) in which the entries look like:

```
{ ["upload/example.gif"]=> array(5) { 
     ["title"]=> string(12) "This is me" 
     ["excerpt"]=> string(24) "This is a photo of a tree" 
     ["img"]=> string(42) "upload/example.gif"
     ["link"]=> string(23) "http://www.google.co.uk" 
     ["source"]=> string(6) "custom" 
   }
}
```

I need to be able to remove any duplicate values in `$array` based on the key. So if my array was:

```
$array = array( ["upload/example.gif"] => etc....
                ["upload/tree.gif"] => etc....
                ["upload/example.gif"] => etc....)
```

I would be able to remove one of the `["upload/example.gif"] => etc....` arrays.

I have tried:

```
$array = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array)));
```

but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys (indexes) in an array. They will be overwritten. All keys are therefore automatically unique.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php `If a key is not specified for a value, the maximum of the integer indices is taken and the new key will be that value plus 1. If a key that already has an assigned value is specified, that value will be overwritten.`

Comment: @netcoder - I believe your comment qualifies as answer.

Comment: @netcoder  - Thanks , this helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netcoder answered the question properly, I just wanted it to show up in the answer box (instead of comment).

You can't have duplicate keys in an associative array (or any array).  By nature of it being an array you can be gauranteed to have unique keys.

BTW if you find duplicate data in different keys you can remove the redundant key by unsetting it.

```
unset($array['delete_me']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php